# Javascript prototype property defined as object

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

i'm trying to create a simple Person object that one of it's prototype's properties will be an object, but this doesn't seem possible because the scope changes.

```
var Person = function() {};

Person.prototype.set = function(data) {
    this.data = data;
};

Person.prototype.update = {
    name: function(name) {
        this.data.name = name;
    }
};

var me = new Person();
me.set({name: 'Achilleas'});
me.update.name('John');
```

You can also run it on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Knorcedger/fj5uY/1/)

Is what I want to achieve possible? I know i can do it by using apply to assign the scope, but i don't really like this solution.

Thank you for spending time on my first question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The issue your experiencing is caused because `this` will refer to the object literal that is created and assigned to the `update` property.  It does not refer to person.  Therefore, referring to `this.data.name` produces an error since the object literal does not have a data property.

I would recommend just extending the prototype of `Person` to include an update method which takes a property to update and a value.  Also add `data` as a property of person.

```
var Person = function() {
   this.data = {};
};

Person.prototype.set = function(data) {
    this.data = data;
};

Person.prototype.update = function(property, value){
   this.data[property] = value;
};

var me = new Person();
me.set({name: 'Achilleas'});
me.update('name','John');
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/fj5uY/7/

Comment: Yeah, i'm aware of that solution as well. But the question is if it is possible to make me.update.name('John') work without using apply or call.